# Oracle Create Table if it does not exist

Tags: java, database, oracle10g, sqlplus

Can anyone point me to the right syntax to use in order to create a table only if it does not currently exist in the database?

I'm currently programming a Java GUI in order to connect to Oracle and execute statements on my database and I'm wondering if I would implement this as a Java constraint or a SQLPlus constraint.

Comment: If you try to create a table that doesn't exist, it will fail.  You could trap that failure.  You could also attempt to select a record with that table name from `USER_OBJECTS` or `USER_TABLES` and check the results.

Comment: you can do it in your java code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, it doesn't make a lot of sense to check whether a table exists or not because objects shouldn't be created at runtime and the application should know what objects were created at install time.  If this is part of the installation, you should know what objects exist at any point in the process so you shouldn't need to check whether a table already exists.

If you really need to, however,

- You can attempt to create the table and catch the `ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object" exception.
- You can query `USER_TABLES` (or `ALL_TABLES` or `DBA_TABLES` depending on whether you are creating objects owned by other users and your privileges in the database) to check to see whether the table already exists.
- You can try to drop the table before creating it and catch the `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" exception if it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you! Our project guidelines are a bit scrambled, so I just wanted input on what is typical for a program that works with databases.

Comment: how about temporary tables?

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi - No difference.  Temporary tables are permanent objects, you'd create them at the same time that you create permanent tables and in the same way.  Oracle does not have local temporary tables that would be created and dropped at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

@Archie I would like to answer your question.
@Piyas De Sorry for stealing your code :).

Just a little update of @Piyas De answer.

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '<<Your table creation Statement>>';
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            IF SQLCODE == -955 THEN
                RAISE;
            END IF;
    END;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Following Procedure -

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE <<Your Table Name>>';
    EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
                IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
                     RAISE;
                END IF;
    END;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '<<Your table creation Statement>>';

END;
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: That appears to delete the table every time. What procedure would create it if it doesn't exist but leave it alone if it does?

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    // insert query for insert new record in your table 
}
catch(Exception Ex)
{
    //if it throw exception then catch it

     int s=Ex.getErrorCode(); // check it for 903 error

     //903 is table not existing error in oracle11g

 // then create your new table here otherwise if table present then record get stored in database
}
```