# missing or invalid option , in creating table due to if not exists

Tags: sql, oracle

i have tried to create a table using if not exists using mysql in sql plus, but i got error

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks (
  2  todo_id int auto_increment,
  3  task_id int);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks (
            *
```

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Comment: There is no `IF NOT EXISTS` option to the `CREATE TABLE` statement in Oracle.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436942/oracle-create-table-if-it-does-not-exist for alternative options.

Comment: Syntax for `DROP TABLE` is here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DROP-TABLE.html#GUID-39D89EDC-155D-4A24-837E-D45DDA757B45

Answer (score 1):

You message indicates that you are using Oracles SQL PLUSand not mysql.,

so use

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
        todo_id NUMBER  GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
            task_id NUMBER(5)
      );
```

Please check the manual, for [more information](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#ADMIN01503)

Comment: The ORA- prefix for the error message and reference to SQL\*Plus indicate he is using Oracle Database (despite what he said).

Comment: thx @WilliamRobertson i was distracted at that moment and i  corrected my answer