# Oracle apex ORA-00905 and ORA-06512

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have the following SQL statement generated by MySQL Workbench. When I run it on Oracle Apex i get these errors. Can someone help identify the problem?

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 592
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 578
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2057

CREATE TABLE Stores (
  Store_ID INT NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT Store_ID PRIMARY KEY,
  Tipo VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  Name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  FinancesOfficer_ID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_Stores_Finances_Officers
    FOREIGN KEY (FinancesOfficer_ID)
    REFERENCES Finances_Officers (FinancesOfficer_ID)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  Owner_ID INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_Stores_Store_Owners
    FOREIGN KEY (Owner_ID)
    REFERENCES Store_Owners (Owner_ID)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Comment: Oracle is not mysql see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62244250/missing-or-invalid-option-in-creating-table-due-to-if-not-exists/62244627#62244627

Comment: `Store_ID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Store_ID PRIMARY KEY,` -- Here you need a comma after the column definition and list the primary key columns in the constraint definition -- `Store_ID INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT Store_ID PRIMARY KEY (Store_ID),`. There might be other problems but since you didn't post nearly enough context to allow further investigation, that's just speculation.

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to use the script generated by mysql workbench to create a database inside oracle apex. i know there are many tweaks that must be done in order for it to work, but I can't find an explanation as to what kinds of things oracle doesn't accept from MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Use SQL Developer. You'll save time and aggravation by using a tool that generates the right syntax in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I tried using Developer. However, the Oracle server that I use is not in my computer but on a remote server inside the university and I don't have the username and password required to make the transition :(

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE TABLE` statement would look as follows; I created two *dummy* master tables so that foreign key constraints have *something* to reference.

```
SQL> create table finances_officers (financesofficer_id int primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table store_owners (owner_id int primary key);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create table stores
  2    (store_id            int,
  3     tipo                varchar2(45) not null,
  4     name                varchar2(45) not null,
  5     financesOfficer_id  int,
  6     owner_id            int,
  7     --
  8     constraint pk_sto primary key (store_id),
  9     --
 10     constraint fk_sto_finoff foreign key (financesofficer_id)
 11       references finances_officers (financesofficer_id),
 12    --
 13    constraint fk_sto_own foreign key (owner_id)
 14      references store_owners (owner_id)
 15    );

Table created.

SQL>
```